# How do I assign resources manually to a task that are not users from Active Directory in Project Server?

Tags: project-server

Good morning.

I hope I'm not asking a question that could've been asked before, but I have been searching throughout this forum without success.

I need to know if it's possible in Project Server to add resources manually to a task the same way you can add resources manually to a task in Office's Project 2013. The Project Server I'm currently working on is for developing purposes, and I have no access to users from Active Directory, and I need to assign local resources to a task in order to know where is saved that data in the Project Server Database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to PWA server settings.
2. Click on Manage Users in the section of Security
3. Create New user
4. Go to the project center and open the project schedule PDP
5. Click on Team build in the section of Project
6. Select user for project team and click on save and close button.
7. Now you can add this resource on your task just edit the project.

you can refer this link
http://projectservercode.com/create-timesheet-in-project-server/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It was exactly what I was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign resource on task by CSOM using this link
http://projectservercode.com/assign-resource-on-task-using-csom/

Comment: Please do not provide just urls for some articles which can answer, instead provide some information why or how it is correct.